# Как сделать на javascript(e) при двойном клике появление окна для ввода чисел?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Отбор товара в простейшем Интернет-магазине. Документ разделён на 2 фрейма. В первом перечислен имеющийся товар (не менее 5 видов) в виде небольшой пиктограммы, названия и цены за единицу. Второй фрейм - "корзина". Если пользователь дважды щёлкает по товару в первом фрейме, то ему предлагается в строке ввода ввести число единиц товара, которое необходимо добавить в корзину. Имеется кнопка очистки корзины. Корзина должна представлять собой отчёт, в котором имеется информация о товаре в корзине и общей сумме.

Answer (score 0):

Используй событие `dblclick`.

**JavaScript:**

```
var button = document.getElementById(button_id);
button.ondblclick = function () {
// Код для вывода окна
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(button_selector).dblclick(function () {
// Код для вывода окна
});
```

Comment: Подробнее можно

Comment: `ondblclick` - событие двойного клика в js. Я привел пример использования этого события. Вместо комментария "**// Код для вывода окна**" вы должны вставить код, который должен выполниться по двойному клику (в вашем случае вывод модального окна для ввода кол-ва товаров) на элемент `button` (вместо `button_id`- указать ид кнопки, вместо `button_selector` - класс или ид кнопки, в вашем случае не кнопка а блок с товаром).

Comment: А в чем у вас конкретно проблема, что имеется на данный момент? Можете привести в пример код? Может я вас не до конца понял

Comment: <blink>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){<code>

        jQuery('ditem').click(function(){
            console.log('Click');
        }).dblclick(function(){
            console.log('Dblclick');
        });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<frameset cols="600,*">
    <frame src="сatalog.html" name="MENU">
    <frame src="shop.html" name="CONTENT">
</frameset>
</blink>
А как работать с фреймами

Comment: А почему ты делаешь это фреймами. Фреймы не могут общаться друг с другом (точнее их содержимое), ты не можешь обращаться к содержимому фрейма извне.